# ffmpeg install fail OSX 11.2.3

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

Can you help me?

I try to install a ffmpeg using a brew, but i can't.
error message

```
==> Installing dependencies for ffmpeg: aom, dav1d, libpng, freetype, fontconfig, frei0r, gmp, bdw-gc, libffi, m4, libtool, libunistring, pkg-config, readline, guile, gettext, libidn2, libtasn1, nettle, p11-kit, openssl@1.1, libevent, c-ares, jemalloc, libev, nghttp2, unbound, gnutls, lame, fribidi, pcre, gdbm, mpdecimal, sqlite, xz, python@3.9, glib, libpthread-stubs, xorgproto, libxau, libxdmcp, libxcb, libx11, libxext, libxrender, lzo, pixman, cairo, gobject-introspection, graphite2, icu4c, harfbuzz, libass, libbluray, libsoxr, libvidstab, libogg, libvorbis, libvpx, opencore-amr, jpeg, libtiff, little-cms2, openjpeg, opus, rav1e, flac, libsndfile, libsamplerate, rubberband, sdl2, snappy, speex, srt, giflib, webp, leptonica, tesseract, theora, x264, x265, xvid, libsodium, zeromq and zimg
==> Installing ffmpeg dependency: aom
==> Pouring aom-3.1.1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/7718423841127802e2aac1c252a9f7480c690e9513b51d509aa81812231487fb--aom-3.1.1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz'
Error: Failure while executing; `tar --extract --no-same-owner --file /Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/7718423841127802e2aac1c252a9f7480c690e9513b51d509aa81812231487fb--aom-3.1.1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz --directory /private/tmp/d20210630-27979-or2mst` exited with 1. Here's the output:
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/Users/xxx/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/7718423841127802e2aac1c252a9f7480c690e9513b51d509aa81812231487fb--aom-3.1.1.big_sur.bottle.tar.gz'
```

Answer (score 1):

i solve this problem,reinstall brew

Answer (score 0):

**Error: Failure while executing; `tar --extract --no-same-owner --file**

sudo # change ownership of the file and will do.

Comment: use sudo brew install ffmpeg,mac  not support,message:
Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.